# Is it possible to submit an embedded excel spreadsheet as a form?

Tags: microsoft-excel, web

I am interested in embedding an excel spreadsheet in a future website. I have been searching for a way to get the info out of the spreadsheet possibly into a form. Or some way that I can get the data from it on the back end. I need the excel functionality, but some way to submit it and use the data. Is it possible to submit the spreadsheet as form data in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) - their spreadsheet can be publicized over the Net, and they allow forms to be created very easily.

[image]

Comment: Are there any drawbacks with using GoogleDocs? Can I embed it in my own interface? Is the data stored in those sheets held onto by google/in the cloud?

Comment: Google Docs is still very simplistic, but should satisfy your needs, especially if you just use it as a data collection point (export to excel and crunch later). Embedding should not be a problem depending on how you structure your code, and yes, the data is **hosted** by google and on the Internet.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't have data exist in the cloud / hosted by google so this solution doesn't work for me. But Thanks for the suggestion!